# Having trouble linking two fields with one another, then implementing them to another model

Tags: django

I'm working on a project which helps users find jobs.

So one of the models, named Oferta is used for details about a job. Someone who is looking for emplooyes, just completes a form which is based on this model, and people will be looking at it.

Here's this model:

```
class Oferta(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dataSolicitare = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    denumireMeserie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    locuri = models.IntegerField()
    agentEconomic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataExpirare = models.DateField()
    experientaSolicitata = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studiiSolicitate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    judet = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    localitate = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cor
```

The COR field is the code asociated to a job. Also, denumireMeserie means job name.

So these should be linked. Let's say, if code 1 means "Cook", these should be link - there will be no other job with a different code, or another job for code 1.

So, in my opinion, these two fields should have a OneToOne relationship between them, if I'm not mistaken.

But these codes and jobs need to be implemented in the database - so they need a model too.

```
class CORMeserii(models.Model):
    CodCOR = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    MeserieCor = models.OneToOneField(CodCOR, max_length=50, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is how I tried to do it, but obviously it won't work, because onetoonefield needs a model as the first parameter.

So, my questions are:

How can I link these two fields as I told you, and then link Oferta.cor to CORMeserii.CodCOR and Oferta.denumireMeserie to CORMeserii.MeserieCor?

(because each job with its code and name should be implemented in the database, then chosen in each Oferta (which means offer))

Comment: How is this different from your question yesterday? Why does Dirk's comment on that question not answer it?

Comment: He just pointed to me that I'm using the FK wrong so I've read more about one to one/many to many/many to many and I think that I need a one to one relationship, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dirk pointed out on your previous question, you have not understood what relationship fields do in Django.

A ForeignKey or a OneToOneField gives you access to the entire related object. This means you can access any of the fields on that related object.

So your Oferta model does *not* need a `denumireMeserie` field; that belongs on the other model, which we might call "Job". Oferta has a *link* to that model, ie a ForeignKey:

```
class Oferta(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and Job has the details of the job:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    denumireMeserie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now you can create a Job and an Oferta for that job:

```
my_job = Job.objects.create(cor=1, denumireMeserie='Cook')
my_oferta = Job.objects.create(job=my_job, ...rest of the fields...)
```

Now you can access the job name via the relationship:

```
print(my_oferta.job.denumireMeserie)
```

which will give you "Cook".

Comment: Okay. I got it now. I thought I would need denumireMeserie for when I need to create an object of model Oferta, when a user completes a form. But now I'm thinking about the fact that in the template, I can use only one dropdown with all the denumireMeserie values from the database, and creating the Oferta with something like my_oferta = Oferta.objects.create(job=job.id ,rest of the fields). (but I need to have a list of all job ids into the template).

Comment: Is this the way to go?